# solved - Flutter - Maintain the size of container when using different device

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my widget of category list want to display

```
  Widget categorylist() {
    return Container(
      height: 35.h,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: category.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          bool isSelected = categoryText == category[index];
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 8),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isSelected ? primaryColor : Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                categoryText = category[index];
                Provider.of<RestaurantProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .getAll(query: searchText, category: categoryText);
              },
              child: Text(
                category[index],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF4C53A5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

It will display the height of the list will change when I use different device, I want to keep it maintain.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjOiY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is not to hardcore height, just use **padding** instead:

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.w, vertical: 8.h),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView.builder(...),)
```

This way your container will be adaptive and text will never be cropped.

Or if it is not the right choice for you you can use `Expanded()` instead of a Container with hardroced height.

Answer (score 0):

Either use padding as the other answer implied, or have you tried wrapping the parts that needs fixed height inside a [sized box](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) component with fixed height? Seems from the image that your fixed part is the area with the bubbles inside, so maybe use a column layout and make the first element fixed with a sized box and the second be your ListView that fills up the rest.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 300.0,
      child: Card(child: Text('your bubbles all, chinese, fast food, ... go here')),
    )
    ListView.builder(...)
  ],
);
```